# How to send the newly created lead link and information on a Odoo Discussion channel using an automation?

Tags: python, automation, hyperlink, odoo, channel

I would like to notify users in a discussion channel everytime a new lead is created.
To do so, I am triggering a python code when an Opportunity is in stage NEW. I would like to do this for leads, but I can't quite find a trigger that triggers when a new lead is created. (I can't see On Create available for leads)

In my python code execution I have:

```
#Find the channel by name
channel = env['discuss.channel'].search([('name', '=', 'biz-dev')], limit=1)

# Post the message to the found channel
if channel:
    for lead in records:
        lead_url = f'/web#id={lead.id}&view_type=form&model=crm.lead'
        notification = f'<div class="crm.lead"><a href="#" class="o_redirect" data-oe-id="{lead.id}">View Lead: {lead.name}</a></div>'

        # Build the message content with the link
        message_content = (
            f"New lead created: {lead.name}\n"
            f"Contact Name: {lead.contact_name}\n"
            f"Phone: {lead.phone}\n"
            f"Description: {lead.description}\n\n{notification}"
        )

        # Post the message to the discussion channel
        channel.message_post(
            body=message_content,
            subtype_xmlid='mail.mt_comment'
        )
else:
    # Handle the case where the channel is not found
    print(f"Channel with name 'biz-dev' not found.")
```

However, when the trigger triggers, I find in channel This:

New lead created: MYLEAD Contact Name: John Doe  Phone: 123-123-123 Description: My description goes here View Lead: MYLEAD

Notice the actual HTML is sent instead of a formatted link.

Thoughts on how to address this? or accomplish what I am trying to do ? I use Odoo SaaS 17

I have been trying different attributes in message_post with no success. Any tips you may have to offer will be greatly appreciated.